# Impact of index on different columns while join

Tags: sql, indexing

lets say we have two tables- table A and table B and both tables have 5 million records each. They have common fields, id and name. i want to check that what would be the impact of index if we apply on join field while joining the tables and what would be the impact of index on select column while joining the tables. below is query

```
select t1.name from table A t1 inner join table B t2 on t1.id=t2.id;
```

on which field shall i create index in order to have faster result. shall i put index on id or name? please help

my expectation is if we put index on id column, then query will give result in shorter duration rather if we put index on name field.

looking for performance improvement

my expectation is if we put index on id column, then query will give result in shorter duration rather if we put index on name field.

Comment: You need index to find a row quickly - not to display its column values.

Comment: trying on SQL server and redshift

Comment: So what happened when you tested it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this query:

```
select t1.name
from tableA t1 inner join
     tableB t2
     on t1.id = t2.id;
```

I would expect the best index to be `tableB(id)`.  This is the key used for the `JOIN`.

Under some circumstances, an index on `tableA(id, name)` might be the best alternative. This would be particularly true if `tableA` were much larger than `tableB`.

Comment: Hi Gordon, could you please help to understand. if you could brief out more. Thanks